# How to get data back from partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-views

I have a partial view (using MVC2 .net) inside a view which is a form. the partial view has a textbox and is strongly typed.

The problem is I can't get the textbox data from the partial view when I post back, for some reason I can get all the view data inputs on the controller but the partial view, doesn't return the textbox data.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to help unless you post a bit more detail and some code. Without that here are some suggestions that might help.

You will need a submit button or some JavaScript to post the form inside the partial. If you have another form on the page which you are submitting, it will not include data from other forms and inputs on the page.

Also to form has to post back to a controller action, a partial just a helper to render a view inside another view.